# How to get Browser cached values using coldfusion

Tags: caching, coldfusion

Using `cacheget()` and `cacheput()` methods, we can manipulate with server side cache in coldfusion. Also for caching a data in browser, we use `cfcache` tag with `action="clientcache"`. But, is there any way to get the browser cached values in coldfusion?

Comment: You want CF to know what the browser has cached? If so, that is impossible. CF can't read anything from the browser unless the browser sends that data to CF itself. In theory if there was a JS API for the browser cache you could use Ajax to post it to CF, but afaik there is not.

Comment: @RaymondCamden Thanks for your valuable response